# React Hook Form useWatch not displaying correct value in component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to display the value of an input based on the ID that's selected. Below is part of the data that is used.

```
const data = {
personId: 1,
people: {
    1: "Spencer",
    2: "Charlie",
    3: "Sam"
  }
};
```

What I want is for when the id changes, the name input will display the person's name. It seems to update the person's name the first time it encounters it, but subsequent changes, the value remains the same

```
function App() {
const { control, register, reset } = useForm({});
  const data = {
    personId: 1,
    people: {
      1: "Spencer",
      2: "Charlie",
      3: "Sam"
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    reset(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <label>PersonId:</label>
        <input type="number" {...register("personId")} min="1" />
      </div>
      <Person {...{ control, register }} />
    </form>
  );
}

const Person = ({ control, register }) => {
  const personId = useWatch({
    control,
    name: "personId", // without supply name will watch the entire form, or ['firstName', 'lastName'] to watch both
    defaultValue: 1 // default value before the render
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Person: </label>
      <input type="text" {...register(`people[${personId}]`)} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-rwf98?file=/src/index.tsx - on the ID scroll up to 3, then back down. The value stays the same.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that may have this issue, I was able to fix it by using setValues to initially set the value on render and using it again when updating the input.

```
function App() {
const { control, register, reset } = useForm({});
  const data = {
    personId: 1,
    people: {
      1: "Spencer",
      2: "Charlie",
      3: "Sam"
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    reset(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <label>PersonId:</label>
        <input type="number" {...register("personId")} min="1" />
      </div>
      <Person {...{ control, register }} />
    </form>
  );
}

const Person = ({ control, register }) => {
  const [people,personId] = useWatch({
    control,
    name: ["people","personId"]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // setValue used here
    setValue(`people.${personId}`, people[personId]);
  }, [peopleId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Person: </label>
      <input type="text" {...register(`people[${personId}]`, {
      onChange: (e) => 
 // and setValue used again here
setValue(`people.${personId}`, e.target.value),
    })} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```